# Adding columns from select to existing table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Let's say I have already a table with two columns and I need to add more columns from a different table. Is there any way to add those columns on the fly?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
     RecordId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     CreatedBackupDate DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

I need to do something like

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable FROM SELECT col1, col2 from dbo.MyTable2
```

I know this is not going to work because the table already exists, I can also get the columns from dbo.MyTable2 with the datatypes and add them with an script, I just want to know if there is an easy way.

Comment: Check out the use of `JOIN` in the select part of your insert. [This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) provides a good explanation of it.

Comment: What I try to do is alter dbo.MyTable adding columns from dbo.MyTable2

Comment: Aaaaahhhhh... In that case, first alter your table (adding the columns) and then update the records.

Comment: To do this on the fly would probably require a dynamic SQL sproc and depending on the size of the tables could take a while. Do you need the data to be joined in a table, or would a view suffice?